# Why don't structs work in Xcode, when they do in Visual C++? Help needed!

Tags: c++, xcode

For some reason, this very basic code will compile with no errors in Visual C++, but gives errors in XCode. I will need to know why, in order to continue working in Xcode for my Computer Science class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct acct {        // bank account data
    int     num;      // account number
    string name;      // owner of account
    float   balance; // balance in account
};

int main() {

    acct account;

    cout << "Enter new account data: " << endl;
    cout << "Account number: ";
    cin  >> account.num;
    cout << "Account name: ";
    cin  >> account.name;
    cout << "Account balance: ";
    cin  >> account.balance;

    return 0;

}
```

It gives two errors, one saying that it expected ';' before account (after main is declared), and the second that account was not declared for cin >> account.num;

Comment: Have you tried declaring the variable as `struct acct account`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is not actually in your code: while C does require you to prefix your variables with `struct` in this case, C++ does not. The problem is actually that there is a global function on Unix named `acct` - it is *this* that is confusing the compiler. If you renamed your struct to something else, say `bank_account`, it will behave as you expected.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the "acct account;" in main to "struct acct account;" it should compile.  You haven't actually declared a new typedef "acct" in your code, but Visual C++ helpfully does one for you as a non-standard extension.  XCode is more strict.

An alternative fix is to do "typedef struct acct { ... } acct;" which will both declare the acct structure and create a new typedef.

Comment: `acct account;` is 100% correct in C++. Maybe `XCode` is broken! or the questioner doesn't know how to compile correctly using `XCode`.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into similar problems trying to use a variable named "log."

If you want to keep your structure name, try specifying just the elements you want to use:

```
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
```